# How to find substring in list and return to substring in list instead of true or false only

Tags: pandas, list, find, substring

Hi i have dataset something like this

```
dx = pd.DataFrame({'IDs':[1234,5346,1234,8793,8793],
                    'Names':['APPLE ABCD ONE','APPLE ABCD','NO STRAWBERRY YES','ORANGE AVAILABLE','TEA AVAILABLE']})

kw = ['APPLE', 'ORANGE', 'LEMONS', 'STRAWBERRY', 'BLUEBERRY', 'TEA COFFEE']
dx['Check']=dx['Names'].apply(lambda x: 1 if any(k in x for k in kw) else 0)
```

instead of returning to 1 or 0 i want it to return to kw like 'APPLE', 'ORANGE' or 'TEA COFFE' in new column

hope anyone can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to benefit from vectorial speed:

```
import re

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, kw))
dx['Check'] = dx['Names'].str.extract(f'({regex})')
```

*NB. this only returns the **first** match, if you want all use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and perform an aggregation step.*

output:

```
    IDs              Names       Check
0  1234     APPLE ABCD ONE       APPLE
1  5346         APPLE ABCD       APPLE
2  1234  NO STRAWBERRY YES  STRAWBERRY
3  8793   ORANGE AVAILABLE      ORANGE
4  8793      TEA AVAILABLE         NaN
```

Comment: I believe I have met this kind of problems many times, but strangely I couldn't find a dupe.

Comment: IIUC OP wants 'TEA COFFEE' instead of 'NaN' in the last row, because 'TEA' is a common term between 'TEA AVAILABLE' and 'TEA COFFEE'. To me, OP needs some string matching library like difflib to solve this.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh could be, they are not always easy to find!

Comment: @SomeDude I don't think so, it looked like a generic example "*kw **like** … TEA COFFEE*", but I'll update if needed

Comment: @mozway, from this statement: *i want it to return to kw like 'APPLE', 'ORANGE' or 'TEA COFFE' in new column* I assumed so. OP can comment.

Comment: Wow awesome, it worked perfectly. 
i just learned python and havent heard about that code yet.

but if i have a lot of row hundred thousand and the list thousand, is it going execute fast ?

Comment: With thousand in the list it should be reasonably fast, give it a try and let us know ;)

Comment: hi i still cant understand the way the code work, can you explain it ?
what function of "map" and re.escape there

Comment: hi it is 2 hours for 400.000 rows it takes so much time, i usually done this with excel. any suggestion ?

Comment: `map` is to apply `re.escape` on each word to ensure any special character is escaped (otherwise the regex would fail). 2h seems like a lot. How big are the texts in which the words are searched? How often do you expect a match? Are there words with high frequency of match? Can you form subgroups that should only match a subset of words?

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
dx['Check']=dx['Names'].apply(lambda x: [k for k in kw if k in x ])
```